# How can I download the spring-framework.zip on the whole?

Tags: spring

I am trying to download spring-framework.zip on the whole but am able to get the jar files separately which removes the error partially.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.(AbstractApplicationContext.java:164)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:89)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.java:58)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:61)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.tutorialspoint.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
One more error is displayed on the spring explorer tab separately

Could not create the view: org.springframework.ide.eclipse.ui.navigator.springExplorer

Pls someone help me to do the spring installation set up in eclipse.If anyone have spring-framework.zip as a whole file, kindly do share and reply for this post asap. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't search and download use maven or gradle and that will take care of all needed jars. Saves you a lot of searching and headaches.

Comment: apart from the jar issues, we need the class files to be imported or we need to place it in some path.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java class was not able to find,where i will get the source files and where to import or in which path i have to place it? really its taking a lot of time, in google i have searched almost all the pages for installation setup, some are older version(spring.jar which are not used anymore),some links are dead,some of them dont have src files,have only dist folder which resolved only jar issues.the bottom line i want to learn spring, hav to do sample spring project

Comment: I think you need to read up on java. The classes are in the jar files you don't need the source files for those classes. Simply use maven, add the needed dependencies and you should be good to go.

Comment: got it.java files are there in the jar files.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend installing [Spring Tool Suite](http://spring.io/tools/sts) directly (or the Spring Tool Suite feature into an existing Eclipse installation) rather than try to fanagle vanilla Eclipse into shape. You will save yourself hours of headaches.

Comment: Thanks for the response.Let me try to use Spring Tool Suite in the existing eclipse but still i need the spring-framework.zip files to run the code right?

Comment: I have installed STS, which removes one of the error.Could not create the view: org.springframework.ide.eclipse.ui.navigator.springExplorer got fixed by installing STS, will try to execute the code now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are managing the jar file dependency manually then some version of jars may not work with other and you can get the conflict in jars even when there are all jars in you class path you may not able to run your project

Comment: May be but the problem with the jar files got fixed,but it was not able to find the java class ClassPathXmlApplicationContext for this i need to import the class files for that i need the spring-framework.zip.m trying to do a sample spring project but m getting stuck with the installation itself and not able to proceed further.even i have followed some links for spring setup but some of them are older version and they are not using anymore(for example spring.jar file) Can you suggest a link that works for spring installation and spring download?